# Using Neo4j Java API with Python Flask application - how?

Tags: flask, neo4j

I have a Flask application that uses Neo4j and is written in Python. Now, I need to use Neo4j's Java API for traversal and other purposes. What would be a starting point to make this work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this from Python. The traversal API and core API are Java-only, and must execute on the machine where Neo4j is running.

This means you either have to be using an embedded Neo4j deployment (which you aren't), or you need to create a custom procedure/function/kernel extension in Java that will use those APIs and be callable in Cypher queries that you make remotely via the Python Neo4j driver.